# What's the best way to store and maintain the order of items?

Tags: mysql, arrays, sorting

I have an EAV table of `pages` that houses the relationship between all pages and the `books` they belong to.

I need to be able to store and manipulate the order of the pages.

Now the obvious solution is to keep a page index for the pages.

```
+---------+---------+------------+
| page_id | book_id | page_index |
+---------+---------+------------+
|       1 |       1 |          1 |
|       2 |       1 |          2 |
|       3 |       1 |          3 |
|       4 |       1 |          4 |
|       5 |       1 |          5 |
|         |         |            |
|       6 |       2 |          1 |
|       7 |       2 |          2 |
|         |         |            |
|       8 |       3 |          1 |
+---------+---------+------------+
```

But now imagine you have 5000 pages, and you move the last page to the front. That means you have to append the `page_index` in 4999 rows, which I imagine can get heavy.

I considered implementing a linked list in MySQL like so:

```
+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| page_id | book_id | prev_page | next_page |
+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|       1 |       1 | NULL      | 2         |
|       2 |       1 | 1         | 3         |
|       3 |       1 | 2         | 4         |
|       4 |       1 | 3         | 5         |
|       5 |       1 | 4         | NULL      |
|         |         |           |           |
|       6 |       2 | NULL      | 7         |
|       7 |       2 | 6         | NULL      |
|         |         |           |           |
|       8 |       3 | NULL      | NULL      |
+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

That way if you move a page, all you have to change is it's own row and the row of the page you swapped with. However, I also need to implement sorting multiple rows at once (and they don't have to be in a "line" (they can be cherry picked from anywhere and combined into a line), and the supporting PHP to accomplish that with this linked list method would be substantially more complex than with a simple `page_index`.

I could also add a column to the `books` table called `page_order` in which I could store a comma delimited array of page indices which would be easier to maintain as the new array would be generated using PHP and not MySQL. But I'm hesitant to do so because array's aren't officially supported by MySQL. It would be more of a hack.

Is there a better solution to my problem?